# Date array to String Array Swift

Tags: swift, string, date

I have a .compactmap function which gets all the dates from the past week and returns them in a Date array:

```
func getCurrentWeek() -> [Date]{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
    let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today)!       

    let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound)
        .compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today) }  // use `compactMap` in Xcode 9.3 and later
        .filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) }

    return days
}
```

I am trying to use this as a label and I need it to be in string format but cannot seem to change the function to return an array of strings. I have tried this:

```
func getCurrentWeek() -> [String]{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
    let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today)!

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none



    let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound)
        .compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today) }  // use `compactMap` in Xcode 9.3 and later
        .filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) }

    let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: days)


    return myStringafd
}
```

But keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Date]' to expected argument type 'Date'

I know what this means but I'm not sure how to get past this problem and fix the error?

Current format:

> [2018-04-08 23:00:00 +0000, 2018-04-09 23:00:00 +0000, 2018-04-10 23:00:00 +0000, 2018-04-11 23:00:00 +0000, 2018-04-12 23:00:00 +0000]

Desired Format:

> ["2018-04-08", "2018-04-09", "2018-04-10", "2018-04-11", "2018-04-12"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
  let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: days)
```

this takes single Date as argument,but you're passing `days` which is array of Dates  , you have to

```
return days.map{ formatter.string(from: $0) }
```

Comment: `let myStrings = days.map{ formatter.string(from: $0) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
for date in arrOfDates{
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let convdate =  dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            print(convdate)
        }
```